# C++ Program to Simulate Kepler's Equations

Tags: c++, simulation, physics, astronomy

So I am trying to make a basic C++ program that calculates the mean, eccentric, and true anomalies as well as the radial distance and velocity of a planet. This is one of my first programs I have worked on, so I know it's not as concise as it could be. I'm just having a hard time getting it to run. I know some of the values might need to be converted to make the units match up, and I can do that later. I just want to know what is causing it not to run. Also in main, I have if statements for every planet; I didn't include the rest because it would just take up too much space.

Ultimately, the goal of the program is to print a table of times, the anomalies, r, and v given the planet name. If you need any clarification, please let me know. Thank you

Thanks in advance

```
const float G = 6.673E-11;
const float solar_m = 1.989E30;
const float mu = G*solar_m;

class Planet
{
  double a, ec, T;
public:
  void SetValues(float, float, float);
  float Calculations();
};

void Planet::SetValues(float m_a, float m_ec, float m_T)
{
  m_a = a;
  m_ec = ec;
  m_T = T;
}

float Planet::Calculations()
{
  //Set up values
  a = a*1.496E11; //AU to m
  T = T*365;   //Period converted to days

  float delta = 0.001;

  float M;
  float E;

  float E1;
  float E2, f_E2;
  float E3, f_E3;

  float f,r,v;

  for(int t; t<T; t++)
    {
      M= sqrt(mu/(a*a*a))*t;
      E1= M;

      E2 = (M-E1+ec*sin(E1))/(ec*cos(E1)-1);
      f_E2 = M-E2+ec*sin(E2);

      E3 = (M-E2+ec*sin(E2))/(ec*cos(E2)-1);
      f_E2 = M-E3+ec*sin(E3);

      if (f_E2<delta)
        E=E2;
      else if (f_E3<delta)
        E=E3;
      else
        cout<<"not enough iterations";

      f = 2*atan(sqrt((1+ec)/(1-ec))*tan(E/2));
      r = (a*(1-ec*ec))/(1+ec*cos(f));
      v = sqrt(mu*(2/r -1/a));

      cout<< t<<"     "<<M<<" "<<E<<" "<<f<<" "<<r<<" "<<v;
    }
};

int main()
{
  int i;
  float t;
  string pName;
  cout<<"What planet do you want to simulate?";
  cin>>pName;

  if (pName.compare("mercury") || pName.compare("Mercury"))
    {
      Planet me;
      me.SetValues(.387, .2056, .24);
      me.Calculations();
    };
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Compile errors?

Comment: *" I just want to know what is causing it not to run. "*  That is pretty broad there.  Can you describe ***how*** it fails?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to lookup how to use a constructor instead of using a 'setValues' function.

Comment: Your code has some pretty bad syntax errors.  This certainly won't compile.  It is also an incomplete example so it's almost impossible to tell what is going on.  Please read [*“How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.  Maybe you can also reduce the total amount of code down to the essential bits.

Comment: Your `setValues` function is incorrect.  Presently, you are assigning the object's data vaues to the parameters.  The syntax should be `data_field = parameter;`

Comment: In your `Calculations` method, you assign `E1=M`; which means they have the same value.  In the equation for `E2` you have `(M-E1`, which yields zero, since `M` and `E1` have the same value due to the previous assignment statement.

Comment: Ok, so I made some changes and got the program to start, but I get "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 't' is being used without being initialized." I initialized t in the loop, so I am not sure what this means. Also I used the method for finding E seen here http://mmae.iit.edu/~mpeet/Classes/MMAE441/Spacecraft/441Lecture16.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't explained your problem, but I'll offer some critiques.

You mix and match your use of `double` and `float`.  This introduces rounding errors.  Pick one and stick with it.

You have some methods that end with `};` (Bracket-Semicolon).  Check the syntax: methods do not end with semi-colons.  Also your if-statement ends with a semi-colon.  Same problem.

Your `main` function, however, does not end.

Comment: I cut off the rest of main function to save room. I made some adjustments, and now I get the error "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 't' is being used without being initialized." I'm not sure why this is because I initialized t in the loop and again in main().

Answer (score 0):

Some of your calculations are bothering me.

```
  M= sqrt(mu/(a*a*a))*t;
  E1= M;

  E2 = (M-E1+ec*sin(E1))/(ec*cos(E1)-1);
  f_E2 = M-E2+ec*sin(E2);
```

In the equation for `E2`, `M` and `E1` have the same value, by definition of the `E1=M` assignment, so this yields:
`E2 = (0+ec*sin(E1))/(ec*cos(E1)-1);`
or
 `E2 = (ec * sin(E1)) / (ec * cos(E1) - 1);`

Is the " - 1" in the denominator correct?  This is preventing factoring out `ec`.

Comment: I can show you the method that I used. I got it here http://mmae.iit.edu/~mpeet/Classes/MMAE441/Spacecraft/441Lecture16.pdf

Comment: That `-1` is probably correct, that does happen in ellipse-related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm does not work because `SetValues` is setting argument values not member values.

Try this:

```
void Planet::SetValues(float m_a, float m_ec, float m_T)
{
    a = m_a;
    ec = m_ec;
    T = m_T;
}
```